# Вопрос по относительным единицам EM

Tags: css

Имеется код:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <style>
  .padded {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 1em;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="padded">
    We have built partnerships with small farms around the world to
    hand-select beans at the peak of season. We then carefully roast in <a href="/batches">small batches</a> to maximize their potential.
  </div>
</body>
```

По логике вещей padding класса padded должен составлять 16 пикселей, и браузер, что Опера, что Хром последних версий указывают именно такое расстояние, однако когда начинаю проверять линейкой в фотошопе, отступ составляет 24 пикселя. И когда уменьшаю, увеличиваю EM единицы, отталкивается именно от этого числа. В чем здесь проблема?

Comment: Вангую что у вас ретина

Comment: HP Elitebook 840g2. Это типо повышенная плотность пикселей, я верно вас понял?

Comment: Да. https://pepelsbey.net/pres/clear-and-sharp/#26 CSS оперирует «логическими» пикселями, а ваш фотошоп «физическими»